# git gc on machine with quota

Tags: git, quota, git-gc

Simple question, I'm trying to run `git gc` on a machine with a quota. Pre-gc, I'm at about 18GB of usage, almost all of which is my cloned git repository. My disk limit is 25GB. During the `git gc` operation, enough temporary files are written to disk to hit my limit and thus cause the `git gc` operation to fail.

I can delete the `.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_*` after the failed operation and get back down to 18GB of usage, but I'd really like to actually complete `git gc` and reclaim a little performance.

Is there some fancy option (or series of other git commands) that I can use that doesn't involve first writing >7GB of temporary files to the disk?

Comment: What version of git are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which part of the `gc` is important for you? You could try running the `git-prune` and `git-repack` parts separately. With `git-prune`, be sure and specify a cutoff date with the `--expire` option. If there are a ton of loose objects in your repo, getting them out of the way first would be helpful.*

With `git-repack`, you can perhaps mess with the depth and window settings to get something small enough to run within the space you have.

* I don't pretend to fully understand all the issues involved, but I do notice that the prune comes *after* the repack in the git-gc code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the best solution is to ask IT for a bigger quota, though I'm still interested to hear workarounds. Today they were feeling generous, but tomorrow... :)

Answer (score -1):

`git prune` is an excellent suggestion, good call Jefromi.

Another thing you can do is compress your other files ; `git gc`; decompress.

`7z` gets amazing compression, but won't preserve hardlinks and Unix owner/group, IIRC.  If you have a quota, the files are probably all owned by your account, so no worries on the first score.  But the safest is `tar c --lzma` if you have it, or just `tar czf` or `cjf`.  If you have a lot of small files, the umm, external(?) fragmentation up to block-size might be significant.